# Talmud's commentaries in english or french

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, translation

Where can I find the following commentaries on the Talmud in english or french?

- Rambam
- Rosh
- Rashi (Rashbam for some massechtot)
- Nimukei Yossef
- Rabbeinu Yonah

Comment: What criteria are you using for "(main) commentaries on the Talmud?" Are you referring to the main text of the Bavli? Why is RaMBa"M on your list?  Why Nimukei Yosef?  Why Rabbeinu Yonah (for the latter, do you mean as a substitute for Rashi)?

Comment: I deleted "main".

Answer (score 1):

- The Rambam's Mishne Torah (Yad) can be found on Chabad.org [here](http://www.fr.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/898317/jewish/Hakdamah.htm) in French and [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/682956/jewish/Mishneh-Torah.htm) in English.
- Rashi (Rashbam for some massechtot) can be found in the ArtScroll Talmud, incorporated into the translation and footnotes.

Can't find Rosh, Nimukei Yossef or Rabbeinu Yonah translated. Not sure why somebody would bother.

Comment: I could understand the Rif or the Rosh

Comment: @sam. Why? If you're at the level of needing/being able to lookup the Rif or Rosh, you are probably fluent in the original language. (Unless you're using it as a crutch to find out Pshat, like we did as teenagers.) Sort of like making kiddie-books from rocket-science. Cute but useless.